# Add Google Sign to Expo app, and server-side session handling

Tags: react-native, google-signin, expo

### Environment

- React Native `0.62`
- Expo SDK Version: `37`
- Platforms(Android and iOS):

### Context

Hi,
I am building an app using **Expo client** and I would like to add **Google Sign in**. I have already created both iOS and Android client ids from Google developer platform console.

Basically, I want to do what **StackOverflow**, and many others do:

- Ask the user to allow the app to access their Google profile info and email, the first time
- Register them as a new user in my backend database using the retrieved data
- After the first authorization, the user can directly sign in to the app with google without having to authorize again
- My backend API will handle user sessions that are independent from Google, which keeps the user connected to the app even when they sign out of their Google account
- If the user is already signed in to their google account, the app automatically signs them in to their account.

---

I have been reading Google documentation and Expo documentation for weeks now and I feel very confused because there are many solutions but they all seems very ambiguous: `expo-google-sign-in`, `expo-google-app-auth`, `expo-app-auth`, `expo-auth-session`

### My questions:

- As far as I understand `expo-google-app-auth` is used for OAuth 2.0 authorization to get a `refreshToken` and a `accessToken` used to make calls to various Google APIs. On the other hand `expo-google-sign-in` is used to make user able to log in to their Google account. Is that right?
- If I am not wrong about `expo-google-sign-in` then this is what I should use for my application, right ? the problem is that it doesn't work with Expo Client, Only in standalone apps according to Expo docs. So I really don't know what to do!
- Are there any tutorials or courses on how to make a React Native App (using Expo and Expo Client) with Google Sign in and server-side user session handling ?

Comment: I feel the exact same way about it. So many "solutions" to the same problem and to me it seems that `expo-auth-session` is the way to go as other packages are deprecated. Though it's documentation is not clear, it gives instructions on how to get provider IDs but  no real example. Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: For me  `expo-google-app-auth` works perfectly fine and I have no issues with it. You should use it too

Comment: Might be over my head here but have you looked into firebase at all? I have heard mixed things but there google sign in seems pretty easy to implement

Comment: Anyone here solved this and has an example to share? I stuck on this for days, trying several expo packages to accomplish server-side authentication without any success...

Comment: This is exactly the frustration I am currently having. Sounds like maybe trying out expo-google-app-auth is the way to go, even thought it's deprecated. I've gotten expo-auth-session working with Google, but for the life of me I can not figure out how to refresh the token. I was able to get a refresh token with some finagling, but then can't refresh the accessToken. So frustrating.

Comment: Looks like I got expo-auth-session working (Google). It logs in, but to refresh I just call google directly with axios. (I don't have a server for my app). In my experimentation, looks like if you create a client id under ios and android, google refreshing does not require a client_secret. To debug, I just create a build for the simulator (ios) expo build -t simulator, and then drag it onto my simulator to run and test. No logs, but with Alerts I was able to figure out that it does seem to refresh successfully. For expo debugging using the same flow, I pass the client_secret.